# python manage.py collectstatic

Tags: python, ubuntu, dashboard, manage.py

right now i'm trying to install DionaeaFR an ubuntu server 16.04. I followed the tutorial https://www.vanimpe.eu/2014/07/04/install-dionaeafr-web-frontend-dionaea-ubuntu/

when I want to run the web server with command "python manage.py collectstatic" without " " i get an error like the one below :

Traceback (most recent call last): File manage.py, line 14, in  file(pidfile, w).write(pid) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /var/run/dionaeafr/dionaeafr.pid

**what should i do guys** Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to change manage.py by this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
if name == "main":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","DionaeaFR.settings")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line    
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

It works in my case!